# How to get list of users having object level permission on Task and Event via apex?

Tags: apex, soql

[image]I have tried below soql but seems not be working.

```
SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Label
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSetId
IN (SELECT ParentId
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE SObjectType = ‘Task’ AND
PermissionsRead = true)
```

Comment: Seems like it *should* be fine. Can you be more explicit what you mean by *not working*?

Comment: @AdrianLarson. Thanks for your reply. Its working fine for only objects which are showing in profile detail view as shown in above picture. But i need to get the list of users which have accessibility on Task and Event object but sadly these are not available on Profile detail page.

Comment: Isn't object level access to Task/Event open to everyone with maybe a few exceptions based on license type (Chatter Free User?).

Comment: @frontendloader. You mean we can only check the license type of Profile and if its not Chatter Free User. Then we can show all of them. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks!!